# how can findout sum of hours worked by an Employee using Mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table in mysql one table called `logindetails` and another one `logoutdetails`

`logindetails` ---->column name as `login_time`

`logoutdetails`---->column name as `logout_time`

I wanted to findout number of hours worked by an user from `login_time` to `logout_time` please let me know i am new in this field:

```
SELECT e.Employee_Name, SUM(hours) 
FROM logindetails e 
INNER JOIN logoutdetails a ON e.Login_Time = a.Logout_Time 
GROUP BY e.Employee_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT e.Employee_Name, HOUR(TIMEDIFF(e.Login_Time,a.Logout_Time) )
FROM logindetails e 
INNER JOIN logoutdetails a ON e.Employee_Name = a.Employee_Name
GROUP BY e.Employee_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.Employee_Name, 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,e.Login_Time, a.Logout_Time)  
FROM   logindetails e 
INNER JOIN logoutdetails a ON e.Empolyee_Name = a.Employee_Name 
GROUP BY e.Employee_Name
```